# Why $w = 10/m$ is the single major Fourier component? (Statistical Mechanics: Entropy, Order Parameters and Complexity 2nd Edition)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fourier-transform, diffusion

An initial density profile $\rho(x,t=0)$ is perturbed slightly away from a uniform density $\rho_0$, as shown in follows

[image]

The density obeys the diffusion equation $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial^2 x}$, where $D = 0.001m^2/s$. The lump centered at $x_0 = 5$ is a Gaussian distribution with $\sigma = 1$, and the wiggle centered at $x = 15$ is a smooth envelop function multiplying $\cos(10x)$.

Now consider what would the density profile $\rho(x,t)$ be like at $t = 10s$?

I have solved the evolution equation for the Gaussian part  and it turns out that $\sigma^2$ has increased by $2%$. However since the wiggle part has no certain function which makes it difficult to solve the evolution equation analytically so I checked out the answer.

The answer says that, for the sinusoid part, a single important Fourier component is $w = 10/m$(btw, what does the unit here mean?). Since the Fourier transformation of the evolution equation is $U(w_x,t) = \phi(w) e^{-Dw^2t}$, where $\phi(w)$ is the Fourier transformation of the wiggle part, thus, the answer on the book says, we now have a factor $\frac{1}{e}=e^{-D\times10^2\times10}$ which is attenuation of 63%. So the wiggle part changes more dramatically than the Gaussian part.

My question is why $w = 10/m$ is the single major Fourier component? Does it have anything to do with the given function $\cos(10x)$? And does $U(w_x,t)$ represent the amplitude of the wiggle part?

Comment: I think the author just meant $w=10\, m^{-1}$ for the units to match (it's the wave number, the unit of $x$ is length, so $m$). Technically, it would rather be $w=10\, rad\cdot m^{-1}$, but in terms of scaling, it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Although I still have no idea what does the unit of $w = 10/m$ mean and if $U(w_x,t)$ represents the amplitude of the wiggle part, I now know how to solve the evolution equation of the wiggle part.

Consider the function of the wiggle part as $\phi(x)=\psi(x) \cos(10x)$, then the Fourier transformation of the density $\rho(x,t)$ of the wiggle part is
$$U(w_x,t) = \psi(w) \pi[\delta(w+10)+\delta(w-10)]e^{-Dw^2t}$$
where $\psi(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(x) e^{-iwx} dx$. The inverse Fourier transformation of $U(w_x,t)$ is
$$\rho(x,t) = \pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(x)dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-iwx}e^{-Dw^2t}[\delta(w+10)+\delta(w-10)] dw$$
then we have
$$\rho(x,t) = \pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(x)dx (e^{-i10x}-e^{i10x})e^{-100Dt}$$
Thus $\rho(x,10)$ is $\frac1e$ of $\rho(x,0)$.

Comment: You made a mistake, you forgot that products become convolutions after a Fourier transform. You rather have:$$U(w,t)=\pi e^{-Dw^2t}(\psi(w-10)+\psi(w+10))$$ By setting $\psi(w)=\delta(w)$, you recover your conclusion. This is motivated by the fact that your final result is only valid in the limit of infinite width of the envelope (which is a good approximation for your problem). Strictly speaking, the Fourier transform of the envelope changes slightly the attenuation, but since if it is broad in real space, it is extremely localised in Fourier space.

Comment: @LPZ, Would you mind providing an answer? Since I am a beginner in this field and what I can do now is just analyze the problem formally, for some points you have mentioned in your  comment, I cannot understand them completely.